# Can the font used by Chromium/Chrome in the Tabs be changed to a larger size?

Tags: fonts, chromium

I have changed my resolution from 1280x800 to 1776x1000 and adjusted all my fonts accordingly, however the tabs in Chromium look very small, the font is nearly impossible to read also the pixel arrangement of the fonts used in Chromium is horrendous.

I have downloaded another browser, and the fonts look better than they do in Chromium, but i love Chromium so want to fix the font problem there. How can i do that?.

Comment: There is a ticket on the Chromium bug tracker that is finally getting some attention: [Issue 143619: No HiDPI support on Linux](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=143619)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, no.  The font sizes are hard-coded into Chromium.  Your only hope is to try to get this added as a feature to Chromium, but I find this very unlikely.

Comment: I can't believe they wouldn't think of this..

Comment: And the new Chrome/Chromium updates look just horrid in Kubuntu :/

Answer (score 1):

I filed a new bug at the chrome project and it was marked as a duplicate of [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=17866). Sadly this one seems to be abandoned and so probably nothing will change ever ... 
Very sad, I can't read the tabs. Still i think chrome/chromium is the most advanced browser. Would love to use it ... but simply can't ...