# Increase icon/font size in Ubuntu 13.10 on some specific locations

Tags: 13.10, icons, fonts, gnome-do

I've just installed Ubuntu 13.10.

I could increase the font size in most places using the tweak tool, however I'm not able to increase it in some specific places (e.g., tab names in chrome, text in gnome-do). I'm also not able to increase the icons size in e.g. the top right panel (e.g., dropbox icon, battery life icon).

Many thanks,

Comment: Re. Chrome tab font size: http://askubuntu.com/questions/90931/can-the-font-used-by-chromium-chrome-in-the-tabs-be-changed-to-a-larger-size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end what worked for me was to change the resolution of the screen.

In the display settings I changed the default for my laptop (1920 x 1080) to 1360 x 768.
Then I played with the font size (Unity Tweak Tool -> Fonts) to make them smaller (the default was too big for the resolution).

Now the icons have a descent size.

Answer (score 0):

Since unity uses a fix size panel, you can not make the icons larger than the actual panel